# How to login properly using HTML and php?

Tags: php, html, authentication

So, I'm creating a simple file share site that takes in only a user name to login. 
   But even when I have the correct user name, the program thinks it's wrong below is my code:

```
<form method ="POST">
    <p> 
        <label for="user">User ID: </label><input type="text" name="userID" id="user" /> 
    </p>
    <p> 
        <input type="submit" name = "LogIn" value="Log In" /> 
        <input type ="reset"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

PHP part

```
<?php
$users = file('users.txt');
if (isset($_POST['LogIn'])) {
    echo $_POST['userID'].'<br>';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($_POST['userID']==$user){
        header("Location: FileShareLogInRedirect.php");
        exit;
    }
}
echo "Wrong ID".'<br>';
?>
```

What I might be doing wrong? It seems like it should work.

Comment: It works only for one user (one raw) in file users.txt.

Comment: Might be a whitespace or capitalized characters. Show the content of the file and what you're submitting

Answer (score 1):

The submit button value does **NOT** get sent along with the POST.

You should not use the submit button to try to pass form values.

```
<form method ="POST">
        <p> 
            <label for="user">User ID: </label><input type="text" name="userID" id="user" /> 
        </p>
        <p> 
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" /> 
            <input type ="reset"/>
        </p>
    </form>
```

PHP part

```
<?php
$users = file('users.txt');
if (isset($_POST['userID'])) {
    echo $_POST['userID'].'<br>';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($_POST['userID']==$user){
        header("Location: FileShareLogInRedirect.php");
        exit;
    }
}
echo "Wrong ID".'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But this doesn't change anything. My program still thinks all the right usernames are wrong

Comment: "doesn't change anything"???! R u kidding??! How about giving a bit of credit to the people trying to help you. Your code would stop at isset($_POST['LogIn'])... so how does my code fix for you "doesn't change anything"... pretty ungrateful... of you...
Here... here is some more help you can continue to be ungrateful for...

 Try adding this to see what you are getting in the loop this: foreach ($users as $user) { echo $user."<br>";}
Or - post the contents of users.txt so we can see what is in it.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't warped

```
echo "Wrong ID".'<br>';
```

in an else statement.
Example:

```
<?php
$users = file('users.txt');
if (isset($_POST['LogIn'])) {
    echo $_POST['userID'].'<br>';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($_POST['userID']==$user){
        header("Location: FileShareLogInRedirect.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    echo "Wrong ID".'<br>';
}
?>
```

Without the *else* statement your *echo* statement will execute every time regardless of weather the login is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Function file() can't process row by row. For processing on any raw like this case, we use function in_array(). Function in_array() we can use only if we have explicit function array(). Because of that, we needs variable $users to be equal array(). Afther that with help of function fopen() and loop While, load array(), and afther that use function in_array().
Here is code:

```
<form method ="POST">
    <p> 
        <label for="user">User ID: </label><input type="text" name="userID" id="user" /> 
    </p>
    <p> 
        <input type="submit" name = "LogIn" value="Log In" /> 
        <input type ="reset"/>
    </p>
</form>

<?php
$users=array();
$fpn=fopen('users.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fpn))
{
    $user=fgets($fpn);
    $user=trim($user);
    $users[]=$user;
}
if (in_array($_POST['userID'], $users)) {
    header("Location: FileShareLogInRedirect.php");
        exit;
}
echo "Wrong ID".'<br>';
?>
```